# Preventing feed URL from from being routed through proxy in Google Reader

Tags: google-reader, feedburner

I've noticed that when I click through to the actual posts of several of my feeds I'm subscribing to in Google Reader, I will get fed through a certain `feedproxy.google.com` link before been redirected to the actual site.

While this doesn't affect normal usage, in a recent visit to China I found that [the Great Firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall_of_China) seems to block URLs linking to that server. Is there anyway to configure/set up the feeds to avoid that proxy?

The proxy link does not seem appear for all my feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the URL for feeds that are powered by [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com). It offers a bunch of tools for the publisher, like number of subscribers, clickthroughs, etc.

Unless the publisher offers the original (or an alternate) feed there isn't a way to get around it. For blogs powered by WordPress, you can try adding `/feed/` to the blog URL (`http://www.example.com/feed/`), but in many cases that will simply force you back to the Feedburner feed.

Answer (score -1):

All feeds which are viewed in Google reader will **Always** go through the feedproxy.google.com if you click on view post(shortcut 'v'). This is a feature which Google reader has created to collect more information about what sort of information is viewed by the user.